# killing a node process restarts with a new PID

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, node.js

I have a node process running in an ubuntu machine

When I do

```
ps -ef | grep node
```

then I can't find the process ID in the list. I have a few other node processes going on.

Then I did

`sudo netstat -lpn |grep :'3019'` //3019 is the port where node is running

Output - `tcp6       0      0 :::3019                 :::*                    LISTEN      15526/app.js`

```
sudo kill -9 15526
```

But it didn't work. It is now running with a new PID.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Updated the title. Every time I kill the process ID it restarts with a new one. That's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this usually happens when a process has a parent that takes care of spawning a new child process if the child dies (is killed).

Look at the process tree using:

```
ps auxf
```

you will find a graphical representation of parent/child process relationship:

```
ripper    1699  0.3  0.4 415992 48220 ?        Ssl  22:20   0:12  \_ /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
ripper    1704  0.0  0.0   7908  4632 pts/0    Ss   22:20   0:00  |   \_ bash
root      2454  0.0  0.0  10244  4020 pts/0    S    22:21   0:00  |   |   \_ sudo -i
root      2455  0.0  0.0   7916  4696 pts/0    S    22:21   0:00  |   |       \_ -bash
root      3195  1.5  0.0   8684  4408 pts/0    S+   22:22   0:51  |   |           \_ htop
```

kill the parent and then the child (if it did not exit by itself)

Another problem may be that cron or other scheduler is starting the process you killed - this needs deep dive into crontab tables and on what else is running on the system...

Comment: Thank you. I had to stop the parent which was pm2 in my case and then was able to kill the child process.

Answer (score 2):

Usually such processes are started and supervised by a service manager (such as systemd), and it's common for the service manager to be configured to restart the service if it crashes.

Your `kill -9` is interpreted as the service crashing – if you actually want to stop it, you have to ask the service manager nicely.

Check if the process is managed by systemd and find out its service name using:

```
systemctl status <pid>
```

If it's managed, stop the service using:

```
systemctl stop <service>
```

Comment: When I issue the command `systemctl status 15526` then I get this `Failed to get unit for PID 15526: No such method 'GetUnitByPID'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ubuntu server and it worked for me

1. get list of processes with port with command `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`
   [image: CMD output (1)]
2. hit command `systemctl status 15402` to get service running on that process id
   [image: CMD output (2)]
3. `sudo systemctl stop session-431899.scope` to stop service
   [image: CMD output (3)]

now your process is gone...! and port is free